# Remove padding below font awesome (CSS icon)

Tags: html, css, html-table, icons, font-awesome

I am trying to remove the padding below font awesome stack icons, have tried everything in my knowledge, and the solutions provided on stack overflow and other websites (from setting the font-size of the parent element to 0px and by inserting borders to  rather than ) but all to no avail.

There is something that i am clearly missing out.

Thank you in advance for solving the question, cheers.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sazeemj/dhvtrh2f/1/

```
//please ignore
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix this by adding changing the height for .fa-stack class

```
.fa-stack { height:1.2em !important; }
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: result]

If this is what you mean, just remove `top: -40px` from `span` tags.

Comment: No, I want it positioned half outside the table.