# remove bottom padding from font awesome icon

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to remove the bottom padding from a font awesome icon. I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42886432/remove-padding-below-font-awesome-css-icon?rq=1) answer, but no success.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/yxq32z07/) is an example. Because of this padding I have an unwanted spacing between the two table rows (see example).

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

.firstrow > td {
    padding-top: 10px;
}

.datarow > td > div {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-top: 5px;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.datarow > td > div > div {
  float: left;
  padding-right: 5px
}
```

```html
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/de750115f0.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<table>
          <tr class="dx-theme-accent-as-text-color" style="font-weight: bold">
            <td>{{frc.version}}</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="firstrow">
            <td>VA</td>
            <td>BA</td>
            <td>Bevétel</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="datarow">
            <td>
              <div>
                <div>-10,25M€</div>
                <i class="fas fa-sort-up" style="font-size: 32px; color: #5cb85c;"></i>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>
                <div>-20,99M€</div>
                <i class="fas fa-sort-up" style="font-size: 32px; color: #d9534f;"></i>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>
                <div>175,52M€</div>
                <i class="fas fa-sort-up" style="font-size: 32px; color: #5cb85c;"></i>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <div style="overflow: hidden; font-size: smaller;">
                <div style="float: left; color: #5cb85c">+0,45</div>
                <div style="float: left; padding: 0px 2px 0px 2px">/</div>
                <div style="float: left; color: #5cb85c">+1,25%</div>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
```

How can I solve it?

EDIT: originally I added all the code to a snippet, but then SO complained, that the post is just only code. So now I'm adding this text, hoping, that it will be enough. I understand, that SO has some rules, but in the past time I got tired of it. I post a fully question with example and it isn't good enough.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: What you're trying probably won't work because there is no padding being applied to that icon. If you inspect and compare the `fas fa-sort-up` to the `fas fa-sort-down`, you'll see that. That bottom space—for the sort up, and the top space—for the sort down, are part of the glyph. What you could try, though, is to find a different glyph that doesn't have this spacing within it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem isn't padding.  The icon occupies all that space.  Use absolute positioning

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

.firstrow > td {
    padding-top: 10px;
}

.datarow > td > div {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-top: 5px;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.datarow > td > div > div {
  float: left;
  padding-right: 5px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/de750115f0.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<table>
          <tr class="dx-theme-accent-as-text-color" style="font-weight: bold">
            <td>{{frc.version}}</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="firstrow">
            <td>VA</td>
            <td>BA</td>
            <td>Bevétel</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="datarow">
            <td>
              <div>
                <div style='position:relative'>-10,25M€
                <i style='position:absolute;right:-25%;font-size: 32px; color: #5cb85c;' class="fas fa-sort-up" ></i></div>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>
                <div style='position:relative'>-20,99M€
                <i class="fas fa-sort-up" style='position:absolute;right:-25%;font-size: 32px; color:#d9534f;'></i></div>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>
                <div style='position:relative'>175,52M€
                <i class="fas fa-sort-up" style='position:absolute;right:-25%;font-size: 32px; color: #5cb85c;' ></i>
              </div></div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
            <div style="overflow: hidden; font-size: smaller;">
                <div style="float: left; color: #5cb85c">+0,45</div>
                <div style="float: left; padding: 0px 2px 0px 2px">/</div>
                <div style="float: left; color: #5cb85c">+1,25%</div>
              </div> 
            </td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
```